# NGINX SSL Connection Refused

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have been trying to setup SSL for my Nginx Server for hours now, but it keeps saying "This site can’t be reached. Connection refused" when I visit my page. Without SSL everything works just fine.

My nginx.conf looks like this:

```
# HTTP SERVER
server {
        server_name  example.com;
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        # WE USE JUST HTTPS
        location / {
            rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
}

# HTTPS Server
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;        # path to your cacert.pem
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;    # path to your privkey.pem

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/client-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/client-error.log;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html /index.html;
    }
}
```

Obviously my server_name is having my correct server name inserted in my file. It would be awesome if someone could help me.

The Nginx server is setup to serve a ReactJS application.

Comment: Did you do the first checks then we know if the server is really running and reachable locally ? 1/ Check if port 443 is listening (netstat -an)  2/ try to access locally with a curl -kv https://localhost/ 3/ If both 1&2 are OK, disable your firewall 1 minute (systemctl stop firewalld on CentOS 7 for example) and check from remote

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The firewall was the issue.